# SE Flair that includes the total number of people reached

Tags: feature-request, flair

In the SE flair available for every SE user, there is an indicator of your total reputation points.

How about a piece of SE flair that includes the total number of people you have reached?

Comment: There's actually little space there to include anything else... What if [this was a lengthy username](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/620.png)? Too many number already, no? Surely a challenge, if this was to be implemented.

Comment: I'm thinking either a flair that is larger in size, or one that simply replaces the total reputation points with the total number of people you have reached.